# Como ler uma planilha com fórmulas

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber se alguém já enfrentou essa questão. Eu tenho um código que lê normalmente dados de uma planilha, porém a aba que eu preciso ler tem fórmulas e apresenta um erro. Eu estou usando o EPPlus quando tento ler a planilha apresenta o erro:

> OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.BadReadException: 'Could not read block - no data!  (position 0x00090AAD)'

Segue o código :

```
public ActionResult Index(FileUploadViewModel model)
  {
      string rootfolder = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
      string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + model.Planilha.FileName;

      FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(rootfolder, filename));
      using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
          ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
          model.Planilha.CopyToAsync(stream);
          using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
          {
              package.SaveAs(file);
          }

      }

      using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
      {
          //ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
          ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
          if (worksheet == null)
          {
              ModelState.AddModelError("", "Planilha está vazia");
          }
          else
          {
              var countrow = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
              for (int row = 2; row < countrow; row++)
              {
                  model.StaffInfoViewModel.StaffList.Add(new StaffInfoViewModel
                  {
                      Scripts = (worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim(),

                  });
              }
          }
      }

      return View(model);
  }
```

Comment: Onde exatamente ocorre o erro? apresente um [mcve]

Comment: Bom dia Leandro, eu estou usando uma planilha que gera um script pra rodar no banco de dados, ela tem uma fórmula, se eu pegar essas linhas e colocar em outra planilha o sistema lê normalmente o problema mesmo é quando lê a planilha com fórmulas, segue o código onde apresenta o erro:   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
          ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
          model.Planilha.CopyToAsync(stream);
          using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))--erro é aqui
          {
              package.SaveAs(file);
          }

      }

Comment: o Erro aponta esse trecho:    ``` using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) { ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial; model.Planilha.CopyToAsync(stream); using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))--erro é aqui { package.SaveAs(file); } } ```

Comment: Ninguém para dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés do EPPlus, utilize o SpreadsheetLight[image: Baixar pacotes do Nuget]

Adicione pelo Nuget os pacotes:
DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Open-XML-SDK
SpreadsheetLight

using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using SpreadsheetLight;